# Can I query several layers with arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, query, arcgis-pro

**Context**

I am currently working on the migration from ArcMap 10.3 to ArcGIS Pro. We have several tools that won't work anymore in ArcGIS Pro and I am checking what native solutions could be used before going to a customized development.

One of the tool we currently have generates a html page when clicking on a parcel and queries 5 different layers (all the layers have the same ID or parcel number).

I would like to migrate it in ArcGIS Pro using **arcpy** and **reportlab** if possible. I thought about reportlab as the html template is basically a table.

**What has been done**

I already used the SearchCursor to extract the fields I was interested in and the where_clause to select only rows I wanted. However, **I managed to do it within 1 layer at a time**.

I checked the forums to see if I could perform spatial queries with arcpy, and I found the MakeQueryLayer, however I do not wish to create a new layer but just **extract information related to a parcel number over 5 feature layers** and display it in a pdf.

I am trying with MakeQueryTable following ArcGIS Pro help/examples online :

```
import arcpy

tableList = ["c:\\path\\Projects\\MyProject1\\sde.sde\\A.CAD_Adresses\\A.CAD_ADRESSE", "c:\\path\\Projects\\MyProject\\sde.sde\\A.CAD_Communes\\A.CAD_COMMUNE", "c:\\path\\Projects\\MyProject\\sde.sde\\A.CAD_Immeubles\\A.CAD_BIENS_FONDS"] 

fieldList = [["A.CAD_ADRESSE", 'EGID'], ["A.CAD_COMMUNE", 'TITRE'], ["A.CAD_BIENS_FONDS", 'EGRID'], ["A.CAD_BIENS_FONDS", 'MUTNUM']]

keyField = "A.CAD_BIENS_FONDS.EGRID"

arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(tableList, keyField, fieldList)
```

I keep getting a runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6316, in MakeQueryTable
raise e
File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6313, in MakeQueryTable
retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.MakeQueryTable_management(*gp_fixargs((in_table, out_table, in_key_field_option, in_key_field, in_field, where_clause), True)))
File "c:\programfiles\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in <lambda> return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))

RuntimeError: Objet : erreur lors de l’exécution de l’outil
```

I also had to adapt the syntax as I also got errors. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880781/syntaxerror-unexpected-character-after-line-continuation-character-in-python)

For this example I only worked with 3 layers, I have 5 to deal with. But the IDs in common will be the EGID and/or the EGRID number.

Comment: Ok Thank you for the clarification. I will update the post.

Comment: i edited your post to make the question easier to read. Is that normal you have a folder named MyProject1 (for adresses) and another named MyProject for similar data ? Please check the location of your data to make sure.

Comment: @gisnside: I checked and this is normal. This is how the folders have been built. I could change the name of myproject1 but it would not change the MyProject folder that has been created when we installed ArcGIS Pro on our machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. There was a syntax error. Instead of writing:

```
"c:\\path\\Projects\\MyProject1\\sde.sde\\layer"
```

I was supposed to write:

```
r'c:\\path\\Projects\\MyProject1\\sde.sde\\layer'
```

I was wondering if this is typical with ArcGIS Pro because the esri tutorials online do not have this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you are missing the `out_table` and `in_key_field_option` parameters.

[Make Query Table](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-query-table.htm) syntax should be:

```
MakeQueryTable_management (in_table, out_table, in_key_field_option, {in_key_field}, {in_field}, {where_clause})
```

The paramaters enclosed in curly brackets are optional, the rest are mandatory.

Example:

```
arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(in_table=tableList, out_table='whatever', in_key_field_option='USE_KEY_FIELDS', in_key_field=keyField)
```

Comment: Ok make sense. I will try and post an update if needed.

Comment: I tried your solution and it does not work.                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):

arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000152: Invalid input data
Failed to execute (MakeQueryTable). I checked my work environment based on this post: https://community.esri.com/thread/111160. I am not sure what is missing.

Comment: @mel: What i posted is still a part of the solution. You should edit your question accourding to this and then you will get more help